# Update table on itself MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I can't figure out how to make this query run.... I want to update the table so that dependent on the uuid it grabs the lowest of the 'last_updated' and updates the 'created_on' ... I keep getting 'cant specify target table' although I don't know why =/ Is it a recursion issue?

```
UPDATE dlp.address AS t1
SET created_on = (SELECT MIN(last_updated) 
                  FROM dlp.address AS t2 
                  WHERE t1.addressuuid = t2.addressuuid);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE  dlp.address AS t1
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  addressuuid, MIN(last_updated) minDate
            FROM    dlp.address
            GROUP BY addressuuid
        ) AS t2 
            ON t1.addressuuid = t2.addressuuid
SET     t1.created_on = t2.minDate
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
UPDATE dlp.address AS t1

  , (SELECT addressuuid, MIN(last_updated) AS minDate 
       FROM dlp.address GROUP BY addressuuid) AS t2

SET t1.created_on = t2.minDate 

WHERE t1.addressuuid = t2.addressuuid
```